# how to print nth column in a file using awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How to print nth column in a file using `awk`?To print the second column of file, I try:

```
#!/bin/bash   
awk '{print $2}' file
```

But if `n` is a variable, how to print nth column of file using `awk`?

```
#!/bin/bash   
n=2
```

Comment: hi,  `awk '{n=2; print $n}` file

Comment: This is a dupe, you can see lots of similar questions on this topic of using shell variables in `Awk`. The title could suggest awk script, but it is all the same, using shell variables in a script (or) command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n=2
awk -v var="$n" '{print $var}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try this, notice the `-v` option:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3

awk -v x=${n} '{print $x}' file
```

From the man page:

```
The option -v followed by var=value is an assignment to be done before 
prog is executed; any number of -v options may be present.
```

For more examples, you could check [Using Shell Variables in Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html)